# Why does Meteor version 1.5 multiple constraints errors on fresh setup?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, mocha.js, meteor-velocity

I have a freshly setup Meteor  project with Mocha test package. I am using Meteor version 1.5 with Mocha. After creating a fresh project with `Meteor create` command and add mocha test package with `Mike:mocha`. When i goto *http://localhost:3000/* i can see velocity report is configure properly. But when i check the mirror website for the Mocha test at for eg *http://localhost:54518/*
i get the following error.

```
our app is crashing. Here's the latest log:
Errors prevented startup:

While selecting package versions:
error: No version of meteor-base satisfies all constraints: @1.1.0, @=1.0.1
Constraints on package "meteor-base":
* meteor-base@1.1.0 <- top level
* meteor-base@=1.0.1 <- top level

No version of mobile-experience satisfies all constraints: @1.0.4, @=1.0.1
Constraints on package "mobile-experience":
* mobile-experience@1.0.4 <- top level
* mobile-experience@=1.0.1 <- top level

No version of mongo satisfies all constraints: @1.1.18, @=1.1.3
Constraints on package "mongo":
* mongo@1.1.18 <- top level
* mongo@=1.1.3 <- top level
* mongo@1.0.8 <- velocity:core 0.4.1 <- mike:mocha 0.3.5

No version of blaze-html-templates satisfies all constraints: @1.0.4, @=1.0.1
Constraints on package "blaze-html-templates":
* blaze-html-templates@1.0.4 <- top level
* blaze-html-templates@=1.0.1 <- top level

No version of reactive-var satisfies all constraints: @1.0.11, @=1.0.6
Constraints on package "reactive-var":
* reactive-var@1.0.11 <- top level
* reactive-var@=1.0.6 <- top level
* reactive-var@1.0.6 <- blaze 2.1.3 <- spacebars 1.0.7 <- templating 1.1.5 <- mike:mocha 0.3.5
* reactive-var@1.0.6 <- blaze 2.1.3 <- templating 1.1.5 <- mike:mocha 0.3.5

No version of tracker satisfies all constraints: @1.1.3, @=1.0.9
Constraints on package "tracker":
* tracker@1.1.3 <- top level
* tracker@=1.0.9 <- top level
* tracker@1.0.8 <- deps 1.0.9 <- htmljs 1.0.5 <- blaze 2.1.3 <- spacebars 1.0.7 <- templating 1.1.5 <- mike:mocha 0.3.5
* tracker@1.0.8 <- deps 1.0.9 <- htmljs 1.0.5 <- blaze 2.1.3 <- templating 1.1.5 <- mike:mocha 0.3.5
* tracker@1.0.8 <- spacebars 1.0.7 <- templating 1.1.5 <- mike:mocha 0.3.5
* tracker@1.0.8 <- blaze 2.1.3 <- spacebars 1.0.7 <- templating 1.1.5 <- mike:mocha 0.3.5
* tracker@1.0.8 <- blaze 2.1.3 <- templating 1.1.5 <- mike:mocha 0.3.5
* tracker@1.0.8 <- observe-sequence 1.0.7 <- blaze 2.1.3 <- spacebars 1.0.7 <- templating 1.1.5 <- mike:mocha 0.3.5
* tracker@1.0.8 <- observe-sequence 1.0.7 <- blaze 2.1.3 <- templating 1.1.5 <- mike:mocha 0.3.5

No version of es5-shim satisfies all constraints: @4.6.15, @=4.1.14
Constraints on package "es5-shim":
* es5-shim@4.6.15 <- top level
* es5-shim@=4.1.14 <- top level
* es5-shim@4.1.14 <- meteor 1.1.10 <- amplify 1.0.0 <- velocity:html-reporter 0.2.1 <- mike:mocha 0.3.5
* es5-shim@4.1.14 <- meteor 1.1.10 <- babel-compiler 5.8.24_1 <- standard-minifier-js 2.1.0
* es5-shim@4.1.14 <- meteor 1.1.10 <- mike:mocha 0.3.5

No version of ecmascript satisfies all constraints: @0.8.0, @=0.1.6
Constraints on package "ecmascript":
* ecmascript@0.8.0 <- top level
* ecmascript@=0.1.6 <- top level
* ecmascript@0.8.0 <- standard-minifier-js 2.1.0
* ecmascript@0.5.7 <- shell-server 0.2.3
* ecmascript@0.1.6 <- random 1.0.5 <- caching-compiler 1.0.0 <- caching-html-compiler 1.0.2 <- templating 1.1.5 <- mike:mocha 0.3.5
* ecmascript@0.1.3 <- caching-compiler 1.0.0 <- caching-html-compiler 1.0.2 <- templating 1.1.5 <- mike:mocha 0.3.5
* ecmascript@0.1.6 <- templating 1.1.5 <- mike:mocha 0.3.5
* ecmascript@0.1.5 <- caching-html-compiler 1.0.2 <- templating 1.1.5 <- mike:mocha 0.3.5
* ecmascript@0.1.3 <- templating-tools 1.0.0 <- caching-html-compiler 1.0.2 <- templating 1.1.5 <- mike:mocha 0.3.5
* ecmascript@0.1.3 <- templating-tools 1.0.0 <- templating 1.1.5 <- mike:mocha 0.3.5
* ecmascript@0.1.6 <- less 2.5.1 <- velocity:html-reporter 0.2.1 <- mike:mocha 0.3.5

No version of insecure satisfies all constraints: @1.0.7, @=1.0.4
Constraints on package "insecure":
* insecure@1.0.7 <- top level
* insecure@=1.0.4 <- top level

While refreshing package catalog to resolve previous errors:
error: DDP connection timed out

Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: I'm up against this issue currently as well.